# How to avoid unneeded dependencies on headers

Tags: cmake

I use cmake version 3.11.0.
I have the following program (in file "c.c"), where headers a.h and b.h are
empty:

```
#include "a.h"
#if 0
#include "b.h"
#endif
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test c)
```

I run "cmake ." to configure it and then "make".
Everything builds fine.
I then "touch b.h" and again run "make" -
Make rebuilds it!

I mean, header b.h is excluded, any changes to it may be ignored.
Why there is a dependency on it?
Is this by design?
Is it possible to avoid it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is known as *header dependencies scanner*, which scans source files and extract names of headers which are `#include`-ed into it.

Because it is scanner, it doesn't try to check `#ifdef` and other logic, which may cause the header to be not used actually.

You may control header dependency scanner in CMake with [include_regular_expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/include_regular_expression.html) command.

E.g., you may disable scanner by

```
include_regular_expression("^$") # Regular expressions matches empty string only
```

(Technically, this doesn't disable scanning process completely, but disables generating of source-header dependency).

Answer (score 0):

So, I could rename "b.h" into, say, "b.v"
and add

```
include_regular_expression("^.*[.](h|hpp|cpp|inl|inc)$")
```

and my "b.v" header will be excluded.
It seems there is no way to exclude certain patterns?
The only thing to remember is to force full rebuild manually next time I do need "b.v"
Thanks